# Non-isomorphic coarsely equivalent spaces

Tags: c-star-algebras

I've been reading about uniform Roe algebras lately and in particular the rigidity problem. I know that in general $C_u^*(X)$ and $C_u^*(Y)$ being *-isomorphic doesn't necessrily imply that $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic as coarse spaces, but rather only coarsely equivalent. I'm thus looking for an example of coarse spaces $X$ and $Y$ which have isomorphic associated Roe algebras but are not themeselves isomorphic as coarse spaces. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by isomorphic as coarse spaces?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I mean so that there are $f:X \to Y$ and $g:Y \to X$ coarse maps which are genuinely inverses in the set-theoretic sense. I've learned in the meantime that the category of coarse spaces is so defined so that two spaces are isomorphic in $\mathbf{Coarse}$ iff they are coarsely equivalent so I can see that my formulation was poorly chosen, but I think the question still makes sense!

Comment: Then how about $X$ being the discrete metric space $\{1,2\}$ and $Y$ being the space $\{1\}$. These are not "isomorphic" in your sense (there can be no bijection between the two) but if i'm not mistaken their uniform Roe algebras should be both just $\mathbb{C}$, no?

Comment: @Justdroppedin The uniform Roe algebra of $Y$ would be $\mathbb{C}$, but the uniform Roe algebra of $X$ would be $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{C})$

Comment: @Aweygan Oh, I have no idea about roe algebras, i just assumed that since the spaces are coarsely equivalent their roe algebras should be isomorphic. Isn't this the case?

Comment: The Roe algebras are isomorphic (both are isomorphic to the algebra of compact operators on a separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space). Their uniform Roe algebras, on  the other hand,  are not isomorphic.